# How to Login programmatically in Django?

Tags: django

I need to login programmatically in Django.I had registered by using normal registration page. but i need to login for a single person by saying the username and password in the program itself.So he is allowed to view the requested page.I don't need user authorization, just to redirect the page if username and password is " given in the program.."

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions

Comment: Also see https://www.kancloud.cn/english/mastering-django/79691

Answer (score 1):

You can use `authenticate` and `login`.

authenticate user credentials to confirm they are valid. If they are, `authenticate` will return a `User` object.
Then use `login` and you are all set.

**Example:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
user = authenticate(request, username="some_user", password="some_password")
if user:
  login(request, user)
```

Use with caution between sessions and make sure you are not mistakenly logging a stranger to an incorrect user.